# Limit of sums and products

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

[image]

[image]

Is there a convenient way to calculate sums like these so you can evaluate the limit? It seems like in most cases you just need to know what it adds up to.

Answer (score 0):

I always just remember that $$1^k + 2^k + \cdots + n^k$$ is equal to some polynomial of order $k+1$ in $n$, but to get the exact formulas, I have to look them up over and over again.

That said, the two I do remember are $$1+1+\cdots 1 = n$$ (duh) and $$1+2+\cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Comment: Hint: the leading term is $n^{k+1}/(k+1)$ as by integration, and the next one always $n^k/2$ !

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'll remember that the next time I'm looking one of the formulas up :P

Comment: Another trick is that the sum of the coefficients must be $1$ (set $n=1$). Together with the above rules, you get $$\frac12,\frac12\\\frac13,\frac12,\frac16\\\frac14,\frac12,\frac14$$ for the coefficients of the sums of naturals, squares and cubes (the sum of cubes is the square of the sum of the naturals, there is no $n$ term).

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that the sum of the $n$ first $k^{th}$ powers is asymptotic to $\dfrac{n^{k+1}}{k+1}$, you derive that the sum of the powers of the even numbers from $2$ to $2n$ is $\sim2^k\dfrac{n^{k+1}}{k+1}=\dfrac12\dfrac{(2n)^{k+1}}{k+1}$ and that of the odd numbers from $1$ to $2n-1$ is the difference, $\sim\dfrac{(2n)^{k+1}}{k+1}-\dfrac12\dfrac{(2n)^{k+1}}{k+1}=\dfrac12\dfrac{(2n)^{k+1}}{k+1}$.

This gives the limits $1$ and $\dfrac34$.